# Peewee and SQLite returning incorrect date format

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, peewee

I have built a web app in Python and Flask and am having trouble pulling the date and time from my SQLite database.

I enter the date into the DB with the following line-
`order.order_placed = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Which with my current example enters the following into the DB -
 
`2018-05-01 12:08:49`

But when I call `order.order_placed` I get `datetime.date(2018, 5, 1)`

Even if I call `str(order.order_placed)` I get `'2018-05-01'`

Can someone help me get the full date and time out of the database? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using DateField instead of DateTimeField?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In case of ORMs such as Peewee provide the relevant models etc. Remember to format code properly (start each line with 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you're using `DateField` when in actuality you want to use `DateTimeField`.

Furthermore, you don't need to call `strftime` before storing the data. Peewee works nicely with Python `datetime` objects.

Comment: That's not an answer.

Comment: Thank you all, I was using the wrong field type in my model!